# GSF to XTF conversion Python

Tags: python, generics, binary, sensors

I'm trying to create a python script that takes binary GSF and converts it to XTF (eXtended Triton Format)

```
    import os
    from gsfpy import open_gsf
    from xtf import XTFFile, XTFPingHeader, XTFPingChannelHeader, XTFPing


    def convert_gsf_to_xtf(gsf_file_path, xtf_file_path):
        # Open the GSF file
        with gsfpy.GSFF(gsf_file_path) as gsf_file:
            # Create an XTF file and add metadata
            xtf_file = XTFFile()
            xtf_file.set_sonar_name("My Sonar")
            xtf_file.set_recording_program_name("My Program")
            xtf_file.set_number_of_channels(gsf_file.number_channels)

            # Loop through each ping in the GSF file
            for ping_number in range(gsf_file.number_pings):
            ping_data = gsf_file.read_ping(ping_number)

            # Create an XTF ping header and add metadata
            ping_header = XTFPingHeader()
            ping_header.set_serial_number(ping_data.serial_number)
            ping_header.set_ping_number(ping_data.ping_number)
            ping_header.set_number_of_channels(gsf_file.number_channels)
            ping_header.set_sonar_depth(ping_data.sonar_depth)
            ping_header.set_frequency(gsf_file.frequency)
            ping_header.set_sample_rate(gsf_file.sample_rate)
            ping_header.set_ping_date(ping_data.datetime)

            # Loop through each channel in the GSF ping
            for channel_number in range(gsf_file.number_channels):
                channel_data = ping_data.channels[channel_number]

                # Create an XTF channel header and add metadata
                channel_header = XTFPingChannelHeader()
                channel_header.set_channel_number(channel_data.channel_number)
                channel_header.set_gain(channel_data.gain)
                channel_header.set_pulse_length(channel_data.pulse_length)
                channel_header.set_sample_rate(gsf_file.sample_rate)

                # Create an XTF ping and add channel data
                ping = XTFPing()
                ping.set_channel_data(channel_number, channel_data.data)

                # Add the channel header and ping to the XTF file
                ping_header.add_channel_header(channel_header)
                ping.add_channel(channel_number, channel_header, channel_data.data)

            # Add the ping header and ping to the XTF file
            xtf_file.add_ping_header(ping_header)
            xtf_file.add_ping(ping_header, ping)

    # Save the XTF file with the same name as the GSF file but with .xtf extension
    xtf_file_name = os.path.splitext(gsf_file_path)[0] + ".xtf"
    xtf_file.save(xtf_file_name)


# Convert all GSF files in the directory to XTF format
gsf_directory = "C:/Users/repco.geo3/Desktop/Working"
for file_name in os.listdir(gsf_directory):
    if file_name.endswith(".gsf"):
        gsf_file_path = os.path.join(gsf_directory, file_name)
        convert_gsef_to_xtf(gsf_file_path, gsf_file_path[:-4] + ".xtf")
```

I am getting the following errors though.. Can anyone help please?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\repco.geo3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gsfpy3_08\bindings.py", line 36, in 
_libgsf = CDLL(*libgsf_abs_path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\repco.geo3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ctypes_*init**.py", line 376, in **init**
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\repco.geo3\Desktop\Working\convert gsf to xtf.py", line 2, in 
from gsfpy import open_gsf
File "C:\Users\repco.geo3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gsfpy_*init*_.py", line 64, in 
mirror_default_gsf_version_submodule(globals())
File "C:\Users\repco.geo3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gsfpy_*init*_.py", line 45, in mirror_default_gsf_version_submodule
gsf_submodule = **import**(gsf_submodule_name, globals_dict, None, ["*"], 0)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\repco.geo3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gsfpy3_08_*init*_.py", line 10, in 
from gsfpy3_08.bindings import (
File "C:\Users\repco.geo3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gsfpy3_08\bindings.py", line 38, in 
raise Exception(
Exception: Cannot load shared library from C:\Users\repco.geo3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gsfpy3_08\libgsf\libgsf03-08.so. Set the $GSFPY3_08_LIBGSF_PATH environment variable to the correct path, or remove it from the environment to use the default version.

Process finished with exit code 1